# how to point name sever to host multiple domains on plesk?

Tags: dns, web-hosting, plesk, nameservers, google-cloud-dns

I'm using google cloud for hosting. I have created VM CentOS with static IP and installed Plesk Web Host Edition. I used google cloud DNS and pointed my domain to google name server.

Now xyz.abc domain is pointing to 1.2.3.4 static ip. The issue is I want to host my abc.xyz domain with it. I don't know which name server I should point to it.

How do I configure it?

Comment: are `xyz.abc` and `abc.xyz` in your post different domains or is that a typo? In "pointed my domain to google name server" is "my domain" = `xyz.abc` or `abc.xyz`?

Comment: xyz.abc and abx.xyz are two different domain in whcih xyz.abc domain is host 
its pointing to static ip of vm using google dns
i want to host abc.xyz on plesk i don't which nameserver i should point

Comment: So have you delegated `abc.xyz` to Google Cloud DNS? What entries are there in your DNS hosting?

Comment: i haven't done anything with abc.xyz thats what i am asking how can i host abc.xyz

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to delegate your domain to Google Cloud DNS and add an `A` record like `abc.xyz. A 1.2.3.4` (note the extra dot). Specific details can be found at docs and various tutorials:

- [adding a domain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2GPVpeAnkM) (you have to set name servers on the domain registrar side afterwards)

  - specific how-to for setting name servers depends on the domain registrar
- [working with records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/) (but actually they showed how to add the record via GUI in the video above)

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you are hosting multiple virtual host webserver in the same GCP Instance using [Plesk Web Host Edition](https://www.plesk.com/editions/). The challenge is: having a single IP address, how to manage different DNS for each webserver?

To be able to do that, first you need to understand how [Plesk Multi Server](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/multi-server-guide/about-plesk-multi-server.77093/) map different DNS requests and have your Cloud DNS have multiple A records pointing to the same Instance Public IP. Here is how to [Manage Records](https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/) in Cloud DNS.